# When is ō romanised ou Vs oh?

Tags: manga, anime, rōmaji, vowels

Top of my head, I think of these 6 anime/manga:

ō's that are 'oh'

1. [Tamaki Suoh](https://ouran.fandom.com/wiki/Tamaki_Suoh) (須王 環 Suō Tamaki) from OHSHC
2. [Ōtsuki](https://kaiji.fandom.com/wiki/Ootsuki) (大槻)  from Kaiji - ok I can't find on the fandom page, but I swear the subs say Ohtsuki instead of Outsuki
3. [Kaname Ohgi](https://codegeass.fandom.com/wiki/Kaname_Ohgi) (扇 要, Ōgi Kaname) from Code Geass

Vs

1. [Shion no Ō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shion_no_%C5%8C) (しおんの王, lit. Shion's King) - Does it count if [MAL romanises](https://myanimelist.net/anime/2562/Shion_no_Ou) as ou not oh?
2. [The Devil Is a Part-Timer!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_Is_a_Part-Timer!) (Japanese: はたらく魔王さま!, Hepburn: Hataraku Maō-sama!, lit. "Working Demon King!" or "Demon Lord at Work!") - Sadao Maou (Satan, 真奥 貞夫, Maō Sadao)
3. [Maoyū: Maō Yūsha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maoyu) (まおゆう魔王勇者, "Demon King and Hero") - I guess similarly it's gonna be Maou Yūsha. (I think Maoyū should even be Maōyū ?)

Guess:

When it's a name, use h? Idk. As for the Maō-sama case, I believe 'Maō' is not really a name but a title similar to 'Maō' in Maōyū.

Comment: It depends entirely on whatever the person presenting it wants to do

Comment: @Angelos eg...?

Comment: The すおう you have given is 'Suoh' in most translations, but for example Tatsuya Suou from Persona is spelled like that (not the same Kanji spelling, but the hiragana is identical). 'Outsuki' is not really an option because it's おおつき, but the translators could have spelled it as any of 'Otsuki', 'Ohtsuki', and 'Ootsuki', just depending on how they wanted to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of names used in passports today, either **o** or **oh** is fine and it is a matter of choice (of the person who applies in case of passport).

E.g., [the guide](https://www.boston.us.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_ja/passport7.html) from the consulate-general of Japan in Boston has the following as allowed romanization for passport names.

| 氏名のフリガナ | ヘボン式ローマ字 | OHによる長音表記 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| オオ | O | OH |
| 例：オオノ | ONO | OHNO |
| コオリ | KORI | KOHRI |
| オウ | O | OH |
| 例：コウノ | KONO | KOHNO |
| オウギ | OGI | OHGI |

As noted in the guide, originally only *o*, which is *the* correct one in Hepburn romanization, was allowed.

The following contains how おう/おお are transcribed in other romanization.

- [Wikipedia/ローマ字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E5%AD%97)

Comment: OHNO - LOL thanks sundowner!!! trololol

Comment: but wait all your passport examples are oh instead of ou ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes. As far as following the rules, *ou* is never used. I edited the answer.